# Autoformat code CTRL+SHIFT+L add a space, between ending quote and parenthesis of string

Tags: intellij-idea

For example when my code says:

```
System.out.println("Printing demo features");
```

I use CTRL+SHIFT+L and Intellij make this:

```
System.out.println("Printing demo features" );
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have custom code styling in place for Java, thus the auto format function tries to match it:

Check `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Spaces` and look for "Within" grouping. See if you have some options marked like "Method call parentheses". If you don't have any custom style in place, simple reset the Java style to default and it should be "fixed".

Obs.: I am on Intellij14, options might be different.

Comment: I try with your suggestion but nothing, i reinstall Intellij a is fixed now.

Comment: Rather radical solution, but worked. That is what matters, I am glad.

Comment: Had the same problem and this didn't work. So what helped me was: "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart..." (added another answer so people find that solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check off `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Spaces > Within > Method call parentheses`
2. If above didn't help: "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart..." (sounds unrelated, but in my case actually solved it)